# what is the diffrence between time varying copula and constant copula

Tags: time, series

Hi everyone I had read a lot of paper about copula and forecasting with copula in time series but I didn't get the point what's the difference between time-varying copula models and constant copula models is when we work with ARMA-GARCH model that's the meaning of time-varying and when we work with ARIMA model we say that our model based on constant copula.
please guys any information I will be thankful

Comment: This should help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205109/time-varying-copula-vs-dynamic-copula